# How to prevent trigger from overwriting values that were explicitly set?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, update, functions

I tried this but doesn't work because `NEW.updated` is never `NULL` (I suppose `NEW` gets populated by the values currently in the row in addition to the values in the update-statement?):

```
create temp table test (
    created  TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated  TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE FUNCTION update_timestamp() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.updated IS NOT NULL THEN
        NEW.updated := now();
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER asdf BEFORE UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_timestamp();
```

How can I make it set `NEW.updated := now();` only when `updated` is not explicitly set in an update-statement? So that the trigger doesn't overwrite me when I want to set the `updated` column manually (eg. `updated=updated`).

Answer (score 1):

`OLD` contains the current values in the table, `NEW` the values like they would be after the `UPDATE`.

If `NEW.updated IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.updated`, it is clear that `updated` must have been changed by the `UPDATE` statement (or a previous trigger).

If `NEW.updated IS NOT DISTINCT FROM OLD.updated`, you cannot know if `updated` was specified in the `UPDATE` statement or not — the `UPDATE` could have set `updated` to the same value that it had before.

So the best you can get is something like

```
IF NEW.updated IS NOT DISTINCT FROM OLD.updated THEN
   NEW.updated := current_timestamp;
END IF;
```

This will not do what you want if you have something like `SET updated = updated`, but there is no remedy for that.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but as you said, it doesn't work with `updated=updated`, which is actually my primary use case for this. For example, a situation like setting a third timestamp column `deleted` which shouldn't affect `updated`

Comment: You need to remove `NOT` from the expression in the suggested solution.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I think the answer is correct as it stands: the value should only be set if it was not explicitly modified the `UPDATE`, i.e. if it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. After lots of research, I found a temporary solution:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_QUERY() INTO query;
```

So I can use the `query NOT ILIKE '%updated%' to check if we need update the` updated` field.

Answer (score -1):

No way to determine does some field was set in UPDATE query text. You may operate with `NEW.updated` and `OLD.updated` values only.

Actions table:

```
OLD.updated    NEW.updated    Action
------------------------------------
NULL           NULL           nothing
NULL           now()          nothing
NULL           NOT now()      nothing
now()          NULL           NEW.updated=OLD.updated
now()          now()          nothing
now()          NOT now()      ?
NOT now()      NULL           NEW.updated=OLD.updated
NOT now()      now()          NEW.updated=OLD.updated
NOT now()      NOT now()      NEW.updated=OLD.updated
```

And compacted form:

```
OLD.updated    NEW.updated    Action
------------------------------------
NULL           any value      nothing
NOT now()      any value      NEW.updated=OLD.updated
now()          NULL           NEW.updated=OLD.updated
now()          now()          nothing
now()          NOT now()      ?
```

Define the action unknown to me. Then convert this table to proper If-ElseIf-Else form...

PS. `now()` means that the difference between field value and current timestamp is negligible small.

--

**UPDATE**

The final expression will be like:

```
IF   (OLD.updated != NOW()) 
  OR (     (OLD.updated = NOW()) 
       AND (NEW.updated IS NULL)
     ) 
THEN SET NEW.updated=OLD.updated
ELSEIF     (OLD.updated = NOW()) 
       AND (NEW.updated != NOW()) 
THEN ?????
END IF;
```